# Behaviour of container std::set during Insertion?

Tags: c++, stl, insert, set

While inserting in a set, does the set internally delete some of the objects multiple times? I tried to insert two objects of type MyClass as in following program but to my surprise it calls the destructor of class with initially inserted value 2 times! I am not able to understand any logic behind this. Can anyone give some idea on the output?
(highlighted as bold)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<set>

 using namespace std;

   struct MyClass 
   {
      double num;

      ~MyClass()
      {
         printf("Destructor called..for val: %lf\n", num);
      }
   };

   typedef int (*fun_comp)(MyClass, MyClass);   

  int
   comp(MyClass a, MyClass b)
   {
      return a.num-b.num;
   }

  int
   main()
   {
      fun_comp fptr;
      fptr = &comp;
      set<MyClass, int (*)(MyClass, MyClass)> b(fptr);

      for(int i=3; i< 5; i++)
      {
         printf("started with i: %d....\n\n", i);
         {
            MyClass m;
            m.num=i*1.134;
            b.insert(m);
            printf("Inserted val: %lf\n", m.num);
         }
         printf("ended....\n\n");
      }

      printf("Done with insert..\n");      
      return 0;
   }
```

**output:**
started with i: 3....

Inserted val: 3.402000

Destructor called..for val: 3.402000

ended....

started with i: 4....

**Destructor called..for val: 4.536000** <------- why this is deallocated before insertion

**Destructor called..for val: 3.402000** <-------  multiple call to destructor for this valued object

**Destructor called..for val: 4.536000** <-------- ??

**Destructor called..for val: 3.402000** <------ again!!

Inserted val: 4.536000

Destructor called..for val: 4.536000

ended....

Done with insert..

Destructor called..for val: 3.402000

Destructor called..for val: 4.536000

Comment: I'd suggest changing from printing 'val' to printing the value of the 'this' pointer in the destructor, along with 'val', as I suspect you will have a clearer understanding of the behavior of your code afterwards.

Comment: thanks but I did it but an not able to conclude any valid reason except that the addresses are stored in different region..                 here is the output sample output..

Comment: started with i: 3....

Inserted val: 3.402000                                               
Destructor called..for val: 3.402000 0x7fff82190a10
ended....

started with i: 4....

Destructor called..for val: 4.536000 0x7fff821908e0
Destructor called..for val: 3.402000 0x7fff821908d0
Destructor called..for val: 4.536000 0x7fff821907d0
Destructor called..for val: 3.402000 0x7fff821907c0
Inserted val: 4.536000
Destructor called..for val: 4.536000 0x7fff82190a10
ended....

Done with insert..
Destructor called..for val: 3.402000 0x998030
Destructor called..for val: 4.536000 0x998060

Comment: Well, the question was answered below. What I was trying to show you was that using 'val' to detect object identity was misleading, since copied objects would have the same 'val', but different 'this' values.

Comment: BTW, the comparison function is also unsuitable for set. It must return true if left hand value is smaller (`return a.num < b.num;`), and false otherwise. Your comparison function returns "true" (or "false") regardless of which is smaller. - By violating the requirements of a `std::set`, you can get any kinds of results.

Comment: Specifically, the comparator must be a 'strict weak ordering': http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The comparator

```
int    
comp(MyClass a, MyClass b)
{
   return a.num-b.num;
}
```

takes its parameters by value. This will create extra copies that are then destroyed.

Passing by reference will work better.

Answer (score 11):

Change the comparison function to use (const) references

```
int comp(const MyClass& a, const MyClass& b)
{
  return a.num-b.num;
}
```

Each time your comp is being called it is creating copies of a and b. These copies are being destroyed when comp exits.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the points made above, your comparison function isn't valid because it doesn't specify a consistent ordering of the values.  If a.num=1 and b.num=2 then comp(a,b) is true, meaning that a "comes before" b, and comp(b,a) is also true, meaning that b "comes before" a.  This makes the behavior of set undefined.

It's better to create a less-than operator for MyClass and let set<>'s default comparison function do the work:
   struct MyClass 
   {
      double num;

```
  ~MyClass()
  {
     printf("Destructor called..for val: %lf\n", num);
  }
  bool operator < (const MyClass &rhs) const
  {
    return num < rhs.num;
  }
};
...
set<MyClass> b;
```